# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

this is my routes code in express. 
when i try to delete or post in postman, appear this error in console

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/src/routes/modelo.js:56:9)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:92:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
    at Parser._parsePacket (/Users/ivanolvera/Movvel/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
```

```
    // delete by id 

    router.delete("/:idModelo", function(req, res, next) {
      const id = req.params.idModelo;
      const sql = `DELETE * FROM Modelo WHERE idModelo=${id}`;
      pool.query(sql, function(err, row, fields) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ error: "Something failed!" });
        }
        res.send("Deleted");
      });
    });
```

Comment: just change `res.status(500).....` to `return res.status(500)....` to stop the execution and return from the query ..

Answer (score 2):

If you're `pool.query()` encounters an error, then you will call `res.send()` twice:

```
   router.delete("/:idModelo", function(req, res, next) {
      const id = req.params.idModelo;
      const sql = `DELETE * FROM Modelo WHERE idModelo=${id}`;
      pool.query(sql, function(err, row, fields) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ error: "Something failed!" });     // first time res.send()
        }
        res.send("Deleted");                                        // second time res.send()
      });
    });
```

Remember, though `res.send()` finishes off an http response, it does not stop the control flow in Javascript. If there is further code to execute in your function, that code will still run.  So, you need either an `if/else` or a `return` to stop the `res.send("Deleted")` from running after you've encountered an error.  Here's the `return`.

```
   router.delete("/:idModelo", function(req, res, next) {
      const id = req.params.idModelo;
      const sql = `DELETE * FROM Modelo WHERE idModelo=${id}`;
      pool.query(sql, function(err, row, fields) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ error: "Something failed!" });
          return;                // <=== add this
        }
        res.send("Deleted");
      });
    });
```

And, here's an `if/else`:

```
   router.delete("/:idModelo", function(req, res, next) {
      const id = req.params.idModelo;
      const sql = `DELETE * FROM Modelo WHERE idModelo=${id}`;
      pool.query(sql, function(err, row, fields) {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send({ error: "Something failed!" });
        } else {
          res.send("Deleted");
        }
      });
    });
```

If you think this "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error is occurring in cases where there was no `pool.query()` error, then there must be some code somewhere else (perhaps middleware) that is also sending a response and we'd have to see that code in order to help you sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.delete("/:idModelo", function(req, res, next) {
  const id = req.params.idModelo;
  const sql = `DELETE * FROM Modelo WHERE idModelo=${id}`;
  pool.query(sql, function(err, row, fields) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send({ error: "Something failed!" });
      return;
    }
    res.send("Deleted");
  });
});
```

You forgot to put a return after the first `res` call. So what happened was it saw ran the first one and since there was no `return` statement it went ahead to run the second one.

So you can solve you error in 2 ways. put the `res.send` in the `else` block or put a `return` keyword after the `res.status`. It doesn't have to return anything. You just need to signal to the function that after it sends a response error it should terminate the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just return  return `next();` in your middleware and it will work for sure.

Comment: only return next();